# DataTables - ignoring sorting of SQL request

Tags: php, sql, datatables

I sort the data in the table by ORDER BY in SQL request. But when I apply DataTables on my table, it changes the sorting completely...I got "bSortable":false in all columns...Does anybody know what is causing this? :( The DataTable code looks like this:

```
oTable = $('#tabulkaKalk').dataTable({
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sDom": '<"H"f>rtS<"F"i>',
        "sScrollY": iHeight,  
        "bFilter": false,      
        "bAutoWidth": true,  
        "bPaginate": false,  
        "bRetrieve":true,
        "aoColumns": [      
            { "sType": "czech", "bSortable":false },
            { "sType": "natural", "bSortable":false },
            { "sType": "natural", "bSortable":false },
            { "sType": "natural", "bSortable":false }

        ]
    });
```

Comment: Which platform do you use? Please also add more tags to the question.